# Horizontally-scrolling div without empty space

Tags: css, html, overflow

Is it possible to have a `div` element with a fixed width, fixed height, and a lot of text on the inside to scroll JUST horizontally?

I think the obvious answer is "yes" but I'm not entirely sure how.

A solution (one that I'm not pleased with aesthetically) is to wrap the text in a very wide `div`, therefore forcing the parent element to scroll horizontally. (I say "force" because, by nature, it scrolls vertically.)  However, the problem with this is that when you scroll all the way to the right, there is empty space.

Sure, you could find the exact length of the text and tweak it to perfection, but I'm not in a position where that is possible.  The text (it's actually a lot of `inline-block` `div` elements but I don't want to confuse you further) varies in length from one minute to the next.

Here is said solution (the one that has extra space on the right side):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
        <!-- the approximate width of the following text = 5000px -->
        <div style="width:5000px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus semper egestas diam non pretium. Suspendisse tristique, metus quis rhoncus fringilla, elit enim placerat neque, et faucibus purus lacus ac ligula. Mauris purus enim, scelerisque non magna in, euismod bibendum mauris. Integer leo magna, convallis quis nisi vitae, sollicitudin rutrum eros. Aenean fermentum cursus rhoncus. Etiam tempor vel sapien nec venenatis. Phasellus risus massa, vulputate in magna eu, viverra pellentesque magna. Aenean a ipsum a dolor tempor rhoncus eget sit amet sapien. Nunc dui felis, iaculis pulvinar erat eu, eleifend elementum lectus. Suspendisse aliquam condimentum nibh ut luctus. Aenean imperdiet aliquet sollicitudin.
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9AH3k/

(Ironically enough, this code box is exactly what I'm looking for, **but how is it made?**)

Comment: Are you asking for a solution or explanation of the code you posted?

Comment: A better alternative to the code I posted; one that does not contain empty space on the right side. (like the code box)

Comment: why not set up a fiddle with your test? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, all you need to do is use `white-space: nowrap;`

Basically, this sets an element's text not to wrap to a new line, which causes the container to be pushed out to the width of the text content. This way you can get rid of your huge width setting, and it will automatically be sized.

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD4z2/

Comment: this will add to his problems!!

Comment: How so? It seems to do what he asked for to me

Comment: Yes, that is the perfect solution.  Not sure why it would confuse me... it's just a property.

Comment: my bad then i guess...misunderstood question......@TakoM. : u myt wanna accept this answer then!! :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2Vh/1/

You just have to use `<pre></pre>` tags instead of `<div> </div>`

```
<pre>
           akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf    akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf    akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf 
               akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf 
               akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf 
               akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf 
            akjsdfasd akjdkdj akjdakdf ajdskjad akj fdakjsd alksjf akldjf aksjf dalksjfd aksjfksjf d jdk akdj adjfdklajd akjdf kjdf akf 
</pre>
```

You asked

> (Ironically enough, this code box is exactly what I'm looking for, but
>   how is it made?)

It is made with `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: +1 as this is definitely the answer to go with if you are looking for something like a code box, where the text is a fixed-width font. I'm not sure if that's what he wants or if he's trying to use it for some other purpose.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but no, I'm not creating a code box.

Comment: @TakoM. It's not used just for code. See here http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2Vh/2/ You can use it for anything, and apply any styles you want.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you could change the font styles of a pre tag. I'm curious, are there any semantic considerations when using it? If not, this could be a better solution than mine.

Comment: @BlakeMann Well, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp it supports all the global and event attributes of html

Comment: Since both of your answers solve my problem, I'm going to go with Blake's because it's just easier to implement and it doesn't mess with the fonts.